# Uploading a canvas image to facebook as Blob of multipart/form-data type

Tags: javascript, facebook, image, post, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to use the facebook api to upload an image from a canvas I save on the page:

```
var file = dataURItoBlob(canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0))

FB.api('/me/photos', 'POST', {
  source: file,
  message: 'photo description'
}, function (response) {
    console.log(response)
  }
)
```

This is the blob convertor:

```
function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
  var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
  var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
  var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
  for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
    ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return new Blob([ab], { type: 'image/jpeg' });
}
```

And I am getting an error: `message: "(#324) Requires upload file"` so it seems the uploader does not recognize the blob as a valid file.

---

UPDATE 1:

I fount this post: [Convert Data URI to File then append to FormData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998908/convert-data-uri-to-file-then-append-to-formdata) about converting blob to formData, tried it like this:

```
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0)
var blob = dataURItoBlob(dataURL)
var fd = new FormData(document.forms[0])
fd.append("canvasImage", blob)

FB.api('/me/photos', 'POST', {
  source: fd .....
```

But still the same error.

---

UPDATE 2:

Even tried this XHR post solution, [Using Facebooks javascript api to post multipart/form-data encoded image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28955469/using-facebooks-javascript-api-to-post-multipart-form-data-encoded-image) and still getting file issue `"Your photos couldn't be uploaded. Photos should be less than 4 MB and saved as JPG, PNG, GIF or TIFF files."`

```
function postImageToFacebook(access_token) {
  var filename = "samplepic.png",
    mimeType = "image/png",
    message = "test comment",
    data = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"),
    encodedPng = data.substring(data.indexOf(',') + 1, data.length),
    imageData = atob(encodedPng);

  // build the multipart/form-data
  var boundary = '----ThisIsTheBoundary1234567890';
  var formData = '--' + boundary + '\r\n'
  formData += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="source"; filename="' + filename + '"\r\n';
  formData += 'Content-Type: ' + mimeType + '\r\n\r\n';
  for (var i = 0; i < imageData.length; ++i) {
    formData += String.fromCharCode(imageData[i] & 0xff);
  }
  formData += '\r\n';
  formData += '--' + boundary + '\r\n';
  formData += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="message"\r\n\r\n';
  formData += message + '\r\n'
  formData += '--' + boundary + '--\r\n';

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open( 'POST', 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me/photos?access_token=' + access_token, true );
  xhr.onload = xhr.onerror = function() {
    console.log( xhr.responseText );
  };
  xhr.setRequestHeader( "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary );
  xhr.send( formData );
}
```

Comment: The API does not make a request in the necessary format (`multipart/form-data`) for you by itself. Go research how to emulate a proper file upload in JavaScript.

Comment: Updated. Still not working

Comment: You can not use `FB.api` for this – it will never make the request in the right format. You need to make your own HTTP POST request, and supply all the necessary parameters like the access token yourself.

Comment: @CBore Yes, I tried that too, see update 2

Answer (score 6):

I figured out, for some reason, the issues was the headers that I tried to apply as a solution for a previous problem... Here is a working solution: https://jsfiddle.net/ilyador/vyne7oh2/8/

```
function fbUpload(token){
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0)
  var blob = dataURItoBlob(dataURL)
  var formData = new FormData()
  formData.append('token', token)
  formData.append('source', blob)

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open( 'POST', 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos', true )
  xhr.onload = xhr.onerror = function() {
    console.log( xhr.responseText )
  };
  xhr.send( formData )
}

function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
  var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
  var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
  var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
  for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) { ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i); }
  return new Blob([ab], { type: 'image/jpeg' });
}
```

Comment: After three days of trying and failing with other solutions, your solution with the help of the jsFiddler post allowed me to get posting canvas photos directly to Facebook from my localhost app.  This is awesome!  One thing to note, the "token" property I used came from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/  Everything just worked!

Answer (score 1):

To upload **directly from canvas to Facebook photos**, this works for me:

```
function postImageToFacebook(token, imageData, message, successCallback, errorCallback) {
  var fd = new FormData();
  fd.append("access_token", token);
  fd.append("source", imageData);
  fd.append("caption", message);

  $.ajax({
      url: "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=" + token,
      type: "POST",
      data: fd,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      success: function (data) {
        successCallback(data);
      },
      error: function (shr, status, data) {
        errorCallback(data);
      },
      complete: function (data) {
        console.log('Completed');
      }
  });
}

function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
  var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
  var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
  var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
  for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
      ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return new Blob([ab], {type: 'image/jpeg'});
}
```

**To use it**

```
// *IMPORTANT*
var FBLoginScope = 'publish_actions'; // or sth like 'user_photos,publish_actions' if you also use other scopes.

var caption = "Hello Facebook!";
var successCallback = ...;
var errorCallback = ...;

var data = $('#your_canvas_id')[0].toDataURL("image/jpeg");
try {
  imageData = dataURItoBlob(data);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}

FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
  if (response.status === "connected") {
    postImageToFacebook(response.authResponse.accessToken, imageData, caption, successCallback, errorCallback);
  } else if (response.status === "not_authorized") {
    FB.login(function (response) {
        postImageToFacebook(response.authResponse.accessToken, imageData, caption, successCallback, errorCallback);
    }, {scope: FBLoginScope});
  } else {
    FB.login(function (response) {
        postImageToFacebook(response.authResponse.accessToken, imageData, caption, successCallback, errorCallback);
    }, {scope: FBLoginScope});
  }
});
```

*Modified from: http://gorigins.com/posting-a-canvas-image-to-facebook-and-twitter/*